# Plymouth not launching on startup?

Tags: grub2, ati, plymouth

So I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10. Steam started having the "GLX context does not support direct rendering" issue, so I decided to go into Software & Updates to switch my graphics driver to fglrx (I have an AMD Turks Radeon 6670 gfx card). Unfortunately, fglrx didn't recognize my monitor resolution so I went back to "Additional Drivers" to switch back to X.Org. The problem was that all of the options for switching display drivers were disabled, and a mysterious fourth radio button appeared saying that I was using a "manually installed driver".

In order to fix this, I booted into Ubuntu recovery mode (Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-24-generic (recovery mode) ) and hit the "dpkg- repair broken packages" option. I rebooted afterward and managed to successfully switch back to the X.Org driver. Upon rebooting, the Ubuntu splash screen did not appear. My monitor was completely black, switched on and off a couple times, then just showed the Ubuntu login screen. It's been doing this to me ever since I managed to fix the graphics driver. The thing is, plymouth still shows the splash screen on shutdown, just not on startup.

Also- I found the solution for the "no direct rendering" issue in the steam forums, so that's at least fixed.

SOLUTIONS I'VE ALREADY TRIED:

- Editing /etc/default/grub to force my monitor's resolution in grub
- Making sure initramfs-tools has FRAMEBUFFER=y in the configuration
- Using update-alternatives on default.plymouth
- Making sure the plymouth.config file has all the correct data
- Installing v86d

One other peculiarity I've noticed is that using videoinfo in grub (vdeinfo doesn't exist and hwinfo isn't in the repos anymore) Only allows me to go up to a resolution of 1024x768 where my monitor's default resolution is 1920x1080.

Please tell me if there's anything I should try!